# Why is my custom UITableViewCell width incorrect on initial load?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, autolayout

There are 2 stipulations to this issue. It CANNOT be solved by either a)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    ...
    [self.tableView reloadData]
}
```

or b)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

a) A does not work as the data for the cells is not present when viewDidAppear is called. The data is fetched asynchronously from the server in a background thread and takes some time to retrieve. ALSO, `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the completion block of this call does not work either. (Yes, that reloadData statement is doing it's job and being executed on the main thread)

b) This should never need to be called from cellForRowAtIndexPath, and is a warning sign of a bigger issue. While calling `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` is solving the width issue, it's coming at a massive cost. 6-10ms per call. cellForRowAtIndexPath must stay under 13.67ms (1/60fps) otherwise you'll get performance issue. This call is causing massive performance issues, and is not the proper solution either.

Now, on to the issue:

1) As you can see in my nib here [https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RUvc.png, my Cell, and ContentView both have widths of 321.

2) I have the following code cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
NSLog(@"TableView     Width: %f", self.tableView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@" ContentView   Width: %f", cell.contentView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"  ContainerView Width: %f", cell.containerView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"   CardView      Width: %f", cell.cardView.frame.size.width);
```

3) After initial load, these are the results/output are scrolling all the way down and back up again 3 times.

```
2015-04-28 11:24:10.026 Roto Forum[82016:683164] TableView     Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:10.026 Roto Forum[82016:683164]  ContentView   Width: 321.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:10.027 Roto Forum[82016:683164]   ContainerView Width: 345.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:10.027 Roto Forum[82016:683164]    CardView      Width: 305.000000
...
... 3 more sets exactly like these removed for brevity ...
...
2015-04-28 11:24:12.867 Roto Forum[82016:683164]  ContentView   Width: 321.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:12.867 Roto Forum[82016:683164]   ContainerView Width: 345.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:12.867 Roto Forum[82016:683164]    CardView      Width: 305.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:12.901 Roto Forum[82016:683164] TableView     Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:12.901 Roto Forum[82016:683164]  ContentView   Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:12.901 Roto Forum[82016:683164]   ContainerView Width: 383.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:12.901 Roto Forum[82016:683164]    CardView      Width: 343.000000
...
... 37 more sets exactly like these removed for brevity ...
...
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164] TableView     Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164]  ContentView   Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164]   ContainerView Width: 383.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164]    CardView      Width: 343.000000
```

The first 5 sets of this code output look like this...

```
2015-04-28 11:24:10.026 Roto Forum[82016:683164] TableView     Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:10.026 Roto Forum[82016:683164]  ContentView   Width: 321.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:10.027 Roto Forum[82016:683164]   ContainerView Width: 345.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:10.027 Roto Forum[82016:683164]    CardView      Width: 305.000000
```

And the last 40 look like this...

```
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164] TableView     Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164]  ContentView   Width: 375.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164]   ContainerView Width: 383.000000
2015-04-28 11:24:20.716 Roto Forum[82016:683164]    CardView      Width: 343.000000
```

The initially loaded cells have ContentView/ContainerView/CardView width values of 321/345/305 while all subsequent times that or any other cell is loaded it has width values of 375/383/343. What gives?

These are the one that are loading initially as they are viewable on the table view from the get go. The last 40 is what I get every time scrolling up and down the table view. Why do I get these incorrect width's on initial load?

**=========================== EDIT: ===========================**

Adding some code as requested in the first comment

heightForRowAtIndexPath: Not implemented as this is an iOS8 Self Sizing Cell.

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCardCell";
    MyCardCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Question *question = [self.questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = question.questionTitle;
    cell.subtitle.text = question.questionText;
    cell.username.text = question.userName;

    NSLog(@"TableView     Width: %f", self.tableView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@" ContentView   Width: %f", cell.contentView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"  ContainerView Width: %f", cell.containerView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"   CardView      Width: %f", cell.cardView.frame.size.width);

    return cell;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@property UINib *myCardCellNib;
```

ViewController.m

viewDidLoad:

```
self.myCardCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCardCellTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:self.myCardCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCardCell"];
[self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:237.0];
[self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
```

table view cell initiatization:

```
#import "MyCardCellTableViewCell.h"

//managers
#import "FFFColorManager.h"

@implementation MyCardCellTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self initializeAppearance];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)initializeAppearance {
    [self initializeFonts];
    [self initializeColors];
}

- (void)initializeFonts {
    self.title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:14.0];
    self.subtitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:12.0];
    self.username.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:10.0];
}

- (void)initializeColors {
    self.respondLabel.backgroundColor = [[FFFColorManager sharedManager] colorForApplicationColorIdentifier:ApplicationColorIdentifierQuestionCardSectionRespondBackground];
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = [[FFFColorManager sharedManager] colorForApplicationColorIdentifier:ApplicationColorIdentifierTableViewBackground];

    UIColor *cardForegroundColor = [[FFFColorManager sharedManager] colorForApplicationColorIdentifier:ApplicationColorIdentifierQuestionCard];
    self.title.backgroundColor = cardForegroundColor;
    self.subtitle.backgroundColor = cardForegroundColor;
}

@end
```

Comment: Post your heightforRow, cellForRow and tavleview and tableviewcell initialization

Comment: @ArunGupta I added them as an edit to my question. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The issue was my initializeFonts call on my custom cell class. Changing the font size changes the height of the cell.

Comment: Good work solving the problem! How did you end up going about the solution? Moving initializeFonts elsewhere, setting them directly in the XIB?